# Force order of execution in Merge-Statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Is there any way to force the order of execution in a merge-statement?

In my merge-statement, a unique index makes the whole statement fail - even though the index would actually be unique after the execution of the whole statement.
The reason for the failure seems to be, that merge executes the insert-part before the update-part. If it did it the other way around, there would not be any issues.

Is there a way to change that behaviour?

PS: I would really like to keep using the merge-statement, since it offers some nice advantages for the triggers running on the table.

Comment: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/

Comment: You probably should post your code together with some sample data and expected result.

Comment: The actual code and the explanation why it actually needs to look like that, would take several pages. I just hope that somebody knows a way how to do it.